# Select an element with a specific title

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is the html structure, I want to select the a-tag element with the title:

```
<div id="featured-page-9">
    <div>
        <div>
            <h2>
                <a href="..." title="Advanced setting">Advanced</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not working with the attribute selector, I made an edit => the title has two words.

Nope still not working. I'm getting the error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title=Advanced setting]
```

Comment: try $('a[title="Advanced setting"]')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('a[title=Advanced]').css('background', 'orange');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BCzMa/1/

If the attribute value has more than one word, just replicate (note that the value must match exactly, both in case and the amount of spaces) the string inside the attribute selector - e.g.

```
$('a[title="Advanced setting"]').css('background', 'orange');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pS9dH/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use the `attribute` selector

```
$('a[title="Advanced"]').foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can follow two methods

```
$(function(){
    // direct accessing
    $('a[title=testtitle]').css('background', 'orange');

    // another method of accessing
    $('.menu a').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('title')); 
    });
});
```

I have implemented them with this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CodyDmd/V6fkd/1/)